# PHP: Best way to iterate through SQL Return

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fetch

I have a table which looks like this and this is my return from the SQL Query:
[image]

Because all fields where the meta_key has the same number belongs together, it is difficult to iterate through that result. It would be very good if I could make a two dimensional array where all keys and values where the meta_key contains a `0` are sticked together and this also with `1`, `2`, and `3`.

My problem now is to code that. Or is there any better way?

At the end I need something like this (iterate trough each field... 0, 1, 2 ...):

```
for($i = 0; $i < $repeater; $i++){
      $price = //product_shops_0_price
      $price_old = //product_shops_0_price_old
      $link = //product_shops_0_link
      $shop = //product_shops_0_shop
      ...
}
```

I was trying to select all values by once to reduce my SQL query. But my problem now is to sort the values like I need them in my for loop...

```
$details = $database_gk->query("SELECT `meta_key`, `meta_value` FROM `fWR6qIN_postmeta` pm WHERE post_id = $pid AND (meta_key like 'product_shops_%_price' OR meta_key like 'product_shops_%_link' OR meta_key like 'product_shops_%_price_old' OR meta_key like 'product_shops_%_shop');";
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but how did you end up with compound data in your table? This should be avoided at all times, for reasons that must be obvious to you now. What I am try to say: Solve the cause, don't battle the symptoms.

Comment: I know... But I have to handle it... Those datas are from a wordpress plugin..

Comment: Start by showing us a bit of code we can work on. This could be a SQL query on your table, if you want to do this in SQL, or PHP code reading the table, if you want to do it in PHP. Also state the exact purpose of your code. What should the outcome be, and why?

Comment: Please provide what you've done so far

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over the table with PHP you could use this code to access parts of column 2:

```
$parts  = explode('_',$row['column2']);
$number = $parts[2];
$type   = implode('_',array_slice($parts,3));
```

There are many other ways to extract the information from column 2, this is just an example.